# Pyserial module isn't installed on PATH

Tags: python, pip, environment-variables, pyserial

I am using pyserial so I can connect to arduino through a serial port. Unfortunately, python cannot find where I installed pyserial. This is the warning I get when I reinstall pyserial:

```
WARNING: The scripts pyserial-miniterm.exe and pyserial-ports.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\Downtown\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

I think this is to do with PATH not having the right location in environment variables, but every time I add

```
C:\Users\Downtown\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts
```

to environment variables, under path, after restarting my computer and the IDE I'm using, and reinstalling pyserial I still get the same warning message, and I run into an error on

```
import serial
```

I've tried reinstalling python, to no avail; I checked the docs, the import statement I'm using is right; I moved the pyserial package to a different location and set its location in the path; I tried to install the package manually, instead of through pip, the package is meant to be extracted on linux. I don't really understand how environment variables work, but from my research, all I need to do is add the pyserial package location to environment variables under path

This is the command I run to install pyserial:

```
pip install pyserial --user
```

This is a screenshot of my environment variables:

[e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoIY1.png)

this is what I get when I run `import sys; print(sys.path)`:

```
['C:\\Users\\Downtown\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Projects\\Scripting\\ArduinoSerialPortReader',
'C:\\Users\\Downtown\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Projects\\Scripting\\ArduinoSerialPortReader',
'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python310.zip',
'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\DLLs',
'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib',
'C:\\Users\\Downtown\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0',
'C:\\Users\\Downtown\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python310\\site-packages',
'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0',
'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who tries to help

Comment: `import serial` depends on PYTHONPATH (or, more generally, `sys.path`), not PATH. The warning is about something that needs to be fixed to run the scripts that come with pyserial, not to be able to import the library in Python; the two problems are unrelated to each other.

Comment: should I add it to the PYTHONPATH, then?

Comment: It's not the _scripts_ directory that needs to be on PYTHONPATH, it's the site-packages directory from the same interpreter, and usually it'll be there already if you're running the same interpreter that `pip` installed into. (An easy way to get this problem is to install into one interpreter but then use a virtualenv or a different interpreter at runtime).

Comment: Anyhow -- could you [edit] the question to include output of `import sys; print(sys.path)` in the same interpreter where `import serial` fails? ([As text, please, not a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122))

Comment: Okay, so there's the problem. You installed the library for Python 3.11 installed in your home directory, but you're trying to use it in a copy of Python 3.10 installed systemwide (maybe via the Microsoft app store?). Those are two different Python interpreters, and you can only use the library in the interpreter you installed it for.

Comment: Any chance there might be a copy of pip in `'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Scripts`? If so, _that_ would be the one you want to install this with if you want it to work with the 3.10 interpreter instead of the 3.11 one. (I don't do Windows, so this is very much a guess). Similarly, if your `python` is the 3.10 one, you might use `python -m pip` instead of `pip` alone.

Comment: I do not have a copy of pip in that location. So I should use a different version of pip? My problems here might be because I unistalled + reinstalled python, maybe I didn't uninstall it properly. I don't know what you mean when you talk about using python -m pip instead of just pip. Also, thank you for continuing to help me

Comment: IT WORKS NOW! TYSM! I'll write up an answer with how I solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had a problem with my PYTHONPATH, not my PATH, it couldn't find the site-packages of my current python version, as it was trying to use the site-packages of a previous update. To solve the problem, I had to make a PYTHONPATH environment variable reference my current python site-packages, and delete the older python version. Thanks for the amazing help, @Charles Duffy